# regarding responsive and non responsive web pages

Tags: html, css, jsp, responsive

I have created two web pages, to see the differences between responsive and non responsive web pages.
I have given width and margin value in css files.

Both pages take its responsive behavior by itself.

This is my css file:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
body {
    background-color: #999999;

}
.signUp {
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    margin: 40px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 200px 0px #2F4F4F;
}
.rowLab {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0px 60px 0px 0px;
}
.in {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.btn {
    background-color: gray;
    color: #2F4F4F;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
}
```

What should I do in this so that it should not show the responsive behavior.
i.e. I want the pages not to shrink when I reduce the screen size.

This my html page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>SignUp</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="webStyle.css">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function contact() {
                var a=document.getElementById("phone").value;
                if(a.length!=10){
                    alert("Check Contact Number !!");
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="signUp">
            <form action="DBinsert" method="get" >
                <br><br>
                <h1 style="font-size: 50px; color: #ffffff" align="center">Register Yourself</h1>
                <br><br><br>


                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="rowLab">First Name</td>
                        <td><input class="in" type="text" name="fname" required autocomplete="on"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="rowLab">Last Name</td>
                        <td><input class="in" type="text" name="sname" required autocomplete="on"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="rowLab">Username</td>
                        <td><input class="in" type="text" name="uname" required autocomplete="on"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="rowLab">Password</td>
                        <td><input class="in" type="password" name="pwd" required autocomplete="off"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="rowLab">Email Id</td>
                        <td><input class="in" type="text" name="email" required autocomplete="on"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="rowLab">Phone NO.</td>
                        <td><input class="in" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" onblur="contact()" required autocomplete="on"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
                    <tr><td></td>
                    <td><input class="btn" type="submit" value="SignUp"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
                        <tr><td></td>
                        <td>

                        <%String sc=(String)request.getAttribute("data"); %>
                        <%if(sc!=null) {%>
                        <b><%= sc %></b>
                        <%} %><br><br>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im puzzled at the fact you don't want 1 page that resizes on screen width...

Comment: I have created a two pages. I just want to know the differences. What parameter makes it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the width to a fixed value, not a percent. This way the page will stay the same size regardless of window or screen size.

Example: `width: 1000px;`, `width: 1000em;` or `width: 1000rem;` **not** `width: 100%;` or `width: 100vw;`.

Comment: You mean to set just number, no suffix after the value. Right?   @TheWhiteAfrican

Comment: Sorry but I have tried all the options, none of them makes changed.

Comment: You need to provide your html as well for me to be able to help you further.

Comment: I have added my jsp page. please check.